# Numpy.linalg.inv or Numpy.linalg.solve Type Error

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to take the inverse by trying to implement $$(X^{T}X)^{-1}X^{T}y$$

However, when doing so, I get the following error: `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc inv`

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv


data = pd.read_csv("Tbill10yr.csv")
X = data.as_matrix()[:,1]
X1 = X[:730]
y_1 = X[1:,].reshape((730,1))
Nobs = y_1.shape[0]
X1 = np.c_[ np.ones( (Nobs,1) ) , X1]
XX = np.dot(X1.T , X1)
Xy = np.dot(X1.T , y_1)

beta_hat = np.dot(inv(XX),Xy)
```

I later figured out that I had to use `beta_hat = np.dot(inv(XX.dtype(float)),Xy)`

Why is it necessary to do so ? Is there a proper way to go abouts this ?

Any explanation is greatly apprecaited.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason may be that your data was not recognized as `float`. From `data.as_matrix` [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html):

> The dtype will be a lower-common-denominator dtype (implicit
>   upcasting); that is to say if the dtypes (even of numeric types) are
>   mixed, the one that accommodates all will be chosen. Use this with
>   care if you are not dealing with the blocks.

You can check the type of your arrays by doing `XX.dtype`.